# How to release the ViewController Object when added to NavigationController?

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, release

First i have added my ViewController to NavigationController like this,

```
SecondViewController *viewControllerObj = [[SecondViewController alloc] init];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:viewControllerObj animated:YES];
[viewControllerObj release];`
```

But this create crash, when i press back button in navigation bar after it pushed to SecondViewController. So i am creating SecondViewController object as property in .h file and releasing 
viewControllerObj in dealloc like this,

Now i am adding my ViewController to NavigationController like this,

in .h file,

```
@property (nonatomic,retain) SecondViewController *viewControllerObj;
```

in .m file,

```
self.viewControllerObj = [[SecondViewController alloc] init];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:self.viewControllerObj animated:YES];

[_viewControllerObj release]; // in dealloc method
```

When i **Analyze** my project this shows Potential Leak on **viewControllerObj** so i have modified my code like this,

```
SecondViewController *temp =  [[SecondViewController alloc] init];
self.viewControllerObj = temp;
[temp release];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:self.viewControllerObj animated:YES];
```

Now i am cleared that Potential Leak

But i dont know whether this is correct or not, is it each viewController object need to declared as Property and released at dealloc ????

Answer (score 0):

> In terms of correctness you can always use an autorelease instead of a
>   release. Autorelease is a delayed release. It schedules the object to
>   receive its release at a later time.

From [Link](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=703441).

So instead of release message use auto-release with your first code.

```
SecondViewController *viewControllerObj = [[[SecondViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:viewControllerObj animated:YES];
```

> **autorelease :** Decrements the receiver’s retain count at the end of the current autorelease pool block.
>
> **release     :** Decrements the receiver’s reference count. (required). You would only implement this method to define your own
>   reference-counting scheme. Such implementations should not invoke the
>   inherited method; that is, they should not include a release message
>   to super.

[Advanced Memory Management Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000994-BAJHFBGH)

Comment: Make sure you should not over release object remove release statement  if any in code or dealloc method.

Comment: checked that also @Bhargavi

Comment: Ok one more thing apart from release case, check your .xib name and make sure it is exact "SecondViewController" if it is not like this then you must use SecondViewController * viewControllerObj = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"< name of your xib file >" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

Comment: i have same name xib file as "SecondViewController", in my case the navigation controller displaying secondviewcontroller but when i hit back button it get crash, for this i am declaring second viewcontroller as property and releasing in dealloc it works fine. but i dont know whether that is correct procedure ???